Numpy slice: is it possible to look up the original array?
Slicing a numpy.ndarray results in a view of the data:
a=np.linspace(0,5,6)
b=a[1:5]
b[0]+=10
a

returns array([ 0., 11.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]).
From b, is it possible to recover the properties and data of a?
I.e., something like b.viewed_array is a would return true, or at least b.viewed_array.shape == a.shape and (b.viewed_array==a).all() is true?

Yes you can use base method to extract the original vector. For instance, in this case
a = np.linspace(0, 5, 6)
b = a[1:5]

# Using the base attribute
original_array = b.base

You can verify original_array is actually a by running the following
print(original_array is a or (a.base is not None and original_array is a.base)) # Should print True
print((original_array == a).all()) #Should print True


Thanks! For some reason, it doesn't work with linspace at least with numpy 1.26, since a linspace turns out to be a view already... Idk  view of what. But it works with a=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])

Actually your question gave me a chance to learn about this new concept of data identity and object identity. Two vectors (extracted versions) that have same data have different object identities because they reside at different memory locations. This is what base attribute is doing as it saves original_array at different mem location.

So, in this case print((original_array == a).all())  would do the magic!

Thanks for pointing out base, I'm not so sure about your edits. Replacing a withc=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5]) leads to b.base is c (and c.base is None), which answers my question, then I'm not sure what the difficulty is with an array defined as linspace, but in that case we have b.base is a.base.

Well linspace should not create any prob though. I checked my numpy version is 1.26.4, what is yours?

It is 1.26.4. I do get (original_array == a).all() but original_array is a returns false, as you say. Whereas with a=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5]) it returns True.

Check a.base.  If None then a is it's own base.  If not you could use a=a.copy() to ensure it's 'original'.

@hpaulj: yes, I've suggested an edit that should be robust.

Another nuance.  Advanced indexing makes a copy, but that may be a reshape view.

@hpaulj: Hm, I think I understand less and less actually. I've created a chat, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/258198/views-of-numpy-ndarray
